# Background fit of spectroscopic data

Tags: fitting, data, nonlinear

I have some x-ray photoelectron spectroscopy data (XPS).
Unfortunately, the system under review, has a rather unpleasant background structure.
In order to remove the background I have the following approach:

1) I recorded a clean spectrum, just giving me the background
[[image: Background data with fit]]

2) I would fit the clean background spectrum (2 Gaussian + 1 Line)

3) Then I want to remove the clean background from the "real" (i.e. with peaks)
   data. However, the background changes a little from spectrum to spectrum.
   Therefore, I cannot just use the fit for the clean background.
[image: Spectroscopic data with the same background. Clearly the background does not fit well.]

Note: The peaks explicitly shall not be fitted in this procedure.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I want to do this in Mathematica, yes.

Comment: Isn't there a physical model behind the background shape? What does it mean "a little" how can we know what is the background and what is the signal without a context? p.s. isn't the core of the problem really about a scientific method in opposition to implementation of a solution in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There is a model, as I wrote: It's 2 gaussians (2 plasmons) superimposed on a line (secondary electron background).
The background does change randomly for different measurements, therefore the clean background has to be adjusted.

Comment: As it stand now your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its not about Wolfram Mathematica programing. If that's not your intention, please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) minimum example of the code you are working on. (notice the links in the comment)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem as presented is about defining a method for XPS data analysis and not about its implementation in Wolfram Mathematica Language.

Comment: @F.H "2 Gaussian + 1 Line" is a mathematical model, not a physical one. Which may be ok too, if you give use some constrains etc.

Comment: I might be reading too much into your mathematical model of "2 Gaussian + 1 line" but you're using "Gaussian" as a kernel in a regression model rather than anything having to do with a probability distribution.  There is no justification given that a Gaussian kernel is more appropriate than a quadratic or any other kernel.  This seems much more like a statistical question rather than a *Mathematica* questions.